# Javascript Alert in META tag

Tags: php, javascript, alert, meta-tags

Is there any way to work an alert to run when I echo a META tag which is refreshing the page?

The goal is to have the page refresh and then the Alert loads.

Example of current line:

```
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0"; URL="contact-test.php">';
```

Comment: Note that this tag seems to be broken, as the `Content` attribute doesn't end.

Comment: yeah, should be: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=contact-test.php" />`

Answer (score 3):

The web is stateless:

- if you want to show the alert whenever the page loads, you should simply handle this event
- if you want to show the alert only when the user reloads the page you should pass a parameter to tell javascript that the page has been reloaded and then show your message only when the parameter is set (you may use a cookie or better a get parameter)

Answer (score 2):

try to add parameter into your url while refreshing (refresh as redirect), and, if parameter exists, show alert?

or maybe just check referer